# Would it be against the law/human rights for the government to monitor all mosques? (UK Law)

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination, religion, human-rights, religious-law

I am of the belief that in my country (England) the government needs to start monitoring ALL mosques on at least a biannual basis similair to the way schools are monitored by OFSTED. I believe this would reduce the amount of radical preaching that slips through the cracks (eg Didsbury Mosque)

Would this be illegal or violate any rights/discrimination laws?

Comment: FWIW, the primary source of the substantive law that applies here would be the human rights protections and human rights precedents of the Council of Europe. In the UK human rights law mostly arises via treaties, since the UK does not have a bill of rights that is effective to override other UK laws, any UK statute authorizing this activity would override existing statutory law, and also the UK has an official established religion unlike the US with other religions protected by choice. But, I don't know, without a fair amount of research, how those legal sources would apply to this situation.

Comment: I'm a citizen of the UK (I was born here), and I've been in a few mosques and I haven't come across any radical preaching. If anything, I found radical thought at school, the Chartists, Marx/Lenin, the abolitionists and an emphasis on thinking for yourself (and others) and self-expression and this despite OFSTED inspections (irony intended), so I'm not sure that your proposal would have much traction in practise, and legally I doubt whether there is much ground to stand on either. Perhaps you need to take your concerns up with OFSTED instead?

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be discriminatory if the government just monitored mosques. I am pretty sutr it would violate the right to freedom of worship.   If they monitored *all* places of worship,  they would be on stronger ground (but could still be challenged on the basis that they were violating freedom of worship).

Note that this is not the forum to discuss whether this would be effective or not, or a proportionate response to perceived problems.

Comment: Could you provide a specific clause or law which would be being violated?

Comment: What is this 'freedom of worship?'

Comment: @TimLymington Article 9 of the European Convention on Human Rights (brought into UK law by the Human Rights Act 1998) guarantees "right to freedom of thought, conscience and religion".  The right to express religion through worship can be restricted "in accordance with law" and in ways "necessary in a democratic society" (so the case would be arguable).

Comment: Not only that, but since it's "selective" treatment, it is very easy to argue under international human rights law that it's discriminatory. The UK is party to almost all agreements that I know of.